# Returning true if successful in deleting the node in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I have an assignment where I have to find the node at the end of the linked list (the one just before the tail) and return it and delete it. If its successful and deleted, I return true, so it's basically a bool function.

So far, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am not able to return the value because I can not figure out how to return both true and a value for a bool function.

Here is the code;

```
bool List::getBack(int & key)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    Node *prev = new Node;
    temp = head;
    if (tail==head)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        while (temp->next != nullptr)
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        tail = prev;
        prev->next = nullptr;
        delete temp;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I do not want anyone solving my question, I just need help with understanding it.

In the main, this is what should happen using this function:

```
while (MyList.getBack(i))
    cout << i << " ";
cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: You do remember the difference between assignment using `=` and comparison for equality with `==`?

Comment: ah yes youre right! in the if statement I forgot the other equal sign. thanks!

Comment: hey, no I am pretty sure that isnt the problem. I will type out a more clear question, thank you for reminding me :)

Comment: What is `key` for? You pass in a non-`const` reference, indicating you want to update it, but you never assign anything to it. Isn't that the 'other return value' you want?

Comment: yes thats true, this is why I am just a bit confused on how exactly I return the value of the key when its bool function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is all wrong.

For one thing, you are `new`'ing temporary `Node` objects that you shouldn't be allocating at all, and you are leaking them.

And, you are not actually outputting the value of the `Node` that you delete.

And, your whole function can be made much simpler, as you don't need to enumerate the whole list at all. You already know the last `Node` in the list since you have a `tail` pointer directly to it, so use that pointer to access the last `Node` directly (you should NOT be using a non-null sentry for the `tail` - if you are, you are making things harder on yourself).

Try this instead:

```
bool List::getBack(int & key)
{
    if (!tail)
        return false;

    key = tail->key; // or whatever the actual field name is ...

    Node *temp = tail;

    tail = tail->prev;
    if (tail)
        tail->next = nullptr;
    else
        head = nullptr;

    delete temp;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will compare everything wrong I have done :)

Answer (score 1):

You have many possibilities to make this happen. If you strictly want to return several things, in your case (`int`, `bool`), you can return a struct or a tuple that carries both values.

The other possibilities is to take a pointer to `int` and return `bool`, or take pointer to `bool` and return `int`, and to take pointers to both `bool` and `int` and return nothing (`void`), or a pointer to a struct which contains `int` and `bool`.

```
struct ComplexResult
{
    int IntegerValue;
    bool IsSomethingTrue;
}
```

**TRICK**: There is one trick you want to be a bit creative: for a `bool`, one bit is enough to encode true|false, hence you can put the true false in the sign bit of the `int`. Thus you can return both `unsigned int` and `bool` with only `int` (you'll only have less many values as if you use `uint`).

Comment: thank you! :) I think taking the pointer to int and returning the bool is the solution to my case in this assignment.

Comment: Nowhere in this thread is there a function that takes a pointer to an `int`, only a reference.